# Show that the property holds for the group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have $(\mathbb{Q}^2,+)$ with the operation $(x,y)+(x',y')=(x+x',y+y')$. For $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ we have that $a\cdot (x,y)=(a\cdot x, a\cdot y)$.

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^2$ be a group homomorphism.

I want to show that $f(a\cdot (x,y))=a\cdot f(x,y)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$.

For that do we have to write $a(x,y)$ as an addition of each component a times to use the operation that's given?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I have shown that $f(a\cdot (x,y))=a\cdot f(x,y)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{N}_0$. To show that it holds for $\mathbb{Z}$ we have to show that $f((−a)\cdot (x,y))=−a\cdot f(x,y)$, or not? But how?

Comment: is $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$? One time you say the former and another the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is supposed to be the case that $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.  My advice would be to think of a small example and see if you can generalize $f(3\cdot (x,y))=f((x,y)+(x,y)+(x,y))=f(x,y)+f(x,y)+f(x,y)=3\cdot f(x,y)$.  What if it were $f((-3)\cdot (x,y))$?  Induction to prove it carefully.

Comment: So do we show by induction that it holds for every natural a and then that the negative values are symmetrical? What would be if a is rational?

Comment: It works also for $a \in {\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: How can we show that for $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: Prove it first for $a \in {\mathbb Z}$. Let $f(\frac{1}{n}(a,b)) = (c,d)$. Then by the result for $a \in {\mathbb Z}$, $f(a,b) = (nc,nd)$, so $f(\frac{1}{n}(a,b))  = \frac{1}{n}f(a,b)$.

Comment: I have shown that $f(a\cdot (x,y))=a\cdot f(x,y)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{N}_0$. To show that it holds for $\mathbb{Z}$ we have to show that $f((-a_\cdot (x,y))=-a\cdot f(x,y)$, or not? But how? @DerekHolt

Comment: Do we have to show that again by induction or does this follow by $f(a\cdot (x,y))=a\cdot f(x,y), a\in \mathbb{N}_0$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: $0 = f(0) = f(a(x,y) + (-a)(x,y)) = f(a(x,y)) + f(-a(x,y))$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)